# How to Execute these statements given beolw as a script in SQL*Plus, not as stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

```
PROCEDURE SP_PROCESS_RATE_PLAN IS
           var_cursor INTEGER;
           prv_rp_update_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
           prv_rp_insert_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
           v_Dummy INTEGER;
           SQL_STATEMENT VARCHAR2(400);
           /* Massage the data into the Rate_Plan table */
           BEGIN


               /*Trigger is dropped and recreated for table PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC */

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER RATE_PLAN_ID_TRIGGER';

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RATE_PLAN_ID_TRIGGER
             before insert on priceview_rate_plan_proc
             for each row
             begin
             select RATE_PLAN_ID_SEQ.nextval into :new.rate_plan_id from dual;
             end;';



                        /* Update the Rate_Period to the same value for all rate_periods*/
                        prv_rp_update_sql:= 'UPDATE  RATE_USAGE_OVERRIDES a
            SET       a.rate_period = ''0''
            WHERE    a.seqnum  NOT IN (SELECT /*+ use_hash(rate_usage_overrides) */
                                                           a.seqnum
                                FROM rate_usage_overrides b
                                WHERE a.type_id_usg = b.type_id_usg
                                AND a.element_id = b.element_id
                                AND a.jurisdiction = b.jurisdiction
                                AND a.provider_class = b.provider_class
                                AND a.corridor_plan_id = b.corridor_plan_id
                                AND ( a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT <> b.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT
                                        OR  a.ADD_FIXED_AMT <> b.ADD_FIXED_AMT
                                                                        OR a.ADD_UNIT_RATE <> b.ADD_UNIT_RATE )
                                                                AND DECODE(a.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',a.INACTIVE_DT) = DECODE(b.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',b.INACTIVE_DT)
                                                                AND a.ACTIVE_DT = b.ACTIVE_DT )

                AND
                                                                (SELECT count(*) from RATE_USAGE_OVERRIDES c
                                                                 WHERE
                                                                         a.type_id_usg = c.type_id_usg
                                 AND a.element_id = c.element_id
                                 AND a.jurisdiction = c.jurisdiction
                                 AND a.provider_class = c.provider_class
                                 AND a.corridor_plan_id = c.corridor_plan_id
                                 AND a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT = c.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT
                                 AND a.ADD_FIXED_AMT = c.ADD_FIXED_AMT
                                                         AND DECODE(a.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',a.INACTIVE_DT) = DECODE(c.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',c.INACTIVE_DT)
                                                         AND a.ACTIVE_DT = c.ACTIVE_DT
                                 AND a.ADD_UNIT_RATE = c.ADD_UNIT_RATE) > 1';

                        var_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
                        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(var_cursor,prv_rp_update_sql,DBMS_SQL.V7);

                v_Dummy:= DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(var_cursor);
                DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(var_cursor);


             COMMIT;







                        LOCK TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC IN EXCLUSIVE  MODE;

                        /* Insert the Rate_Plan data */

                        prv_rp_insert_sql := 'insert into PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC
                                 (SSR_CODE,
                                 CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID,
                                 CORRIDOR_PLAN_DESCRIPTION,
                                 USAGE_TYPE,
                                 PRODUCT,
                                 JURISDICTION,
                                 PROVIDER,
                                 RATE_PERIOD,
                                 FLAGFALL,
                                 RATE,
                                 RATEBAND,
                                 NUMSECS,
                                 BAND_RATE,
                                 ACTIVE_DT,
                                 INACTIVE_DT)
                                 select /*+ use_hash(rate_usage_overrides,corridor_plan_id_values,product_elements,descriptions,jurisdictions,rate_usage_bands_overrides) */
                                 distinct
                                 decode(a.corridor_plan_id,0, '''', (select c.short_display from corridor_plan_id_values c where a.corridor_plan_id = c.corridor_plan_id)) AS SSR_CODE,
                                 a.corridor_plan_id AS CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID,
                                 decode(a.corridor_plan_id,0, '''', (select d.display_value from corridor_plan_id_values d where a.corridor_plan_id = d.corridor_plan_id)) AS CORRIDOR_PLAN_DESCRIPTION,


                                 decode(a.type_id_usg,0, '''', (select f.description_text from usage_types e, descriptions f where a.type_id_usg = e.type_id_usg and e.description_code = f.description_code)) AS USAGE_TYPE,

                                 decode(a.element_id,0, '''', (select h.description_text from product_elements g,descriptions h where a.element_id = g.element_id and g.description_code = h.description_code)) AS PRODUCT,

                                 decode(a.jurisdiction,0, '''', (select j.description_text from jurisdictions i,descriptions j where a.jurisdiction = i.jurisdiction and j.description_code = i.description_code)) AS JURISDICTION,

                                 decode(a.provider_class,0, '''', (select k.display_value from provider_class_values k where a.provider_class = k.provider_class)) AS PROVIDER,
                                 decode(a.rate_period,''0'', '''',(select l.display_value from rate_period_values       l where a.rate_period = l.rate_period)) AS RATE_PERIOD,
                                 (a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT/100) + (a.ADD_FIXED_AMT/10000000) AS FLAGFALL,
                                 (a.ADD_UNIT_RATE/10000000) * 60 AS RATE,
                                 b.RATEBAND AS RATEBAND,
                                 b.NUM_UNITS AS NUMSECS,
                                 (b.UNIT_RATE/10000000) * 60 AS BAND_RATE,
                                 a.ACTIVE_DT AS ACTIVE_DT,
                                 a.INACTIVE_DT AS INACTIVE_DT
                                 from rate_usage_overrides a,
                                 rate_usage_bands_overrides b
                                 where a.seqnum = b.seqnum(+)';



            var_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

                DBMS_SQL.PARSE(var_cursor,prv_rp_insert_sql,DBMS_SQL.V7);

                v_Dummy:= DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(var_cursor);

                DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(var_cursor);

                         COMMIT;

                         /* Create the indexes */
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_RATE_PLAN_ID';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_USAGE_TYPE';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_SSR_CODE';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS_PROV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PD_JR_PV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_JURIS';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_PROV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROV';


                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID, USAGE_TYPE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RRP_RATE_PLAN_ID ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(RATE_PLAN_ID) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_SSR_CODE ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(SSR_CODE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_USAGE_TYPE ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT) TABLESPACE PRV_Index  STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, JURISDICTION) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, JURISDICTION, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PD_JR_PV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, JURISDICTION, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_JURIS ON  PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, JURISDICTION) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PROVIDER)  TABLESPACE PRV_Index  STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';

                         /* Cut over to the new tables */
                         LOCK TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN IN EXCLUSIVE  MODE ;

                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_X';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_X RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC';

                         /* Remove the old data */
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC';

                END SP_PROCESS_RATE_PLAN;

END PRICEVIEW_PROCESS_EXTRACT;
```

I am new to SQL , so no Idea about the above code so I need help in converting this procedure to SQl script

Comment: what do you mean by **not as stored procedure** ?

Comment: not as stored procedure mean , all the above query shoyuld be written in SQl query itseems.

Comment: can we use SET NOCOUNT ON query before stored procedure

Comment: because the above stored procedure is taking a lot of time approximately 22 hrs to get executed ...so need help in this to reduce execution of stored procedure script.

Comment: Query optimization depends on the number of records and type of join. This is not that simple as you are doing lots of stuffs inside your procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many factors, which affects query performance :

1. Network traffic
2. Table JOINS
3. Number of records in each tables.
4. Indexing and many more...

I can see inside your procedure, you are executing lot of `DDL`and `DML` queries, which definitely impact procedure performance.

What you can do is, you can execute each `DDL` and `DML` query individually and see, which query taking longer time. If you were able to find out that query, which impacting the procedure performance. Then, you can analyze the query and related tables for better performance. Also, remove unnecessary code like dropping/creating trigger (It's not good idea to use trigger as temporary objects, since you are creating and dropping the trigger in each procedure execution).

Comment: Actually I didnot understand your point fo view. so little skeptical about the solutino u have given

Comment: what is not clear ? I have already mentioned the factors, which affects performance. Also, I have pointed out reason in your procedure, which probably improve overall performance. Now, what else you wanted like to know  ?

Comment: Since I am a front end developer..no idea about this sql, since i have to solve this issue , so cant understand what changes to be done.i tried executing all the querys individually, everything is taking 30 mins..and if i delete alll those trigger statements doesnt it affect the script.

Comment: I am bothering you.. i am sorry, but i am in very needy help from you.
can you tell me how to replace above given  stored procedure with plain SQL in a script .my mail id is gangaskotikal@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It might work

```
declare 
           var_cursor INTEGER
           prv_rp_update_sql VARCHAR2(4000)
           prv_rp_insert_sql VARCHAR2(4000)
           v_Dummy INTEGER
           SQL_STATEMENT VARCHAR2(400)
           /* Massage the data into the Rate_Plan table */
           BEGIN


               /*Trigger is dropped and recreated for table PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC */

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TRIGGER RATE_PLAN_ID_TRIGGER';

             EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RATE_PLAN_ID_TRIGGER
             before insert on priceview_rate_plan_proc
             for each row
             begin
             select RATE_PLAN_ID_SEQ.nextval into :new.rate_plan_id from dual;
             end;';



                        /* Update the Rate_Period to the same value for all rate_periods*/
                        prv_rp_update_sql:= 'UPDATE  RATE_USAGE_OVERRIDES a
            SET       a.rate_period = ''0''
            WHERE    a.seqnum  NOT IN (SELECT /*+ use_hash(rate_usage_overrides) */
                                                           a.seqnum
                                FROM rate_usage_overrides b
                                WHERE a.type_id_usg = b.type_id_usg
                                AND a.element_id = b.element_id
                                AND a.jurisdiction = b.jurisdiction
                                AND a.provider_class = b.provider_class
                                AND a.corridor_plan_id = b.corridor_plan_id
                                AND ( a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT <> b.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT
                                        OR  a.ADD_FIXED_AMT <> b.ADD_FIXED_AMT
                                                                        OR a.ADD_UNIT_RATE <> b.ADD_UNIT_RATE )
                                                                AND DECODE(a.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',a.INACTIVE_DT) = DECODE(b.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',b.INACTIVE_DT)
                                                                AND a.ACTIVE_DT = b.ACTIVE_DT )

                AND
                                                                (SELECT count(*) from RATE_USAGE_OVERRIDES c
                                                                 WHERE
                                                                         a.type_id_usg = c.type_id_usg
                                 AND a.element_id = c.element_id
                                 AND a.jurisdiction = c.jurisdiction
                                 AND a.provider_class = c.provider_class
                                 AND a.corridor_plan_id = c.corridor_plan_id
                                 AND a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT = c.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT
                                 AND a.ADD_FIXED_AMT = c.ADD_FIXED_AMT
                                                         AND DECODE(a.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',a.INACTIVE_DT) = DECODE(c.INACTIVE_DT,NULL,''00/00/0000'',c.INACTIVE_DT)
                                                         AND a.ACTIVE_DT = c.ACTIVE_DT
                                 AND a.ADD_UNIT_RATE = c.ADD_UNIT_RATE) > 1';

                        var_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
                        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(var_cursor,prv_rp_update_sql,DBMS_SQL.V7);

                v_Dummy:= DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(var_cursor);
                DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(var_cursor);


             COMMIT;







                        LOCK TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC IN EXCLUSIVE  MODE;

                        /* Insert the Rate_Plan data */

                        prv_rp_insert_sql := 'insert into PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC
                                 (SSR_CODE,
                                 CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID,
                                 CORRIDOR_PLAN_DESCRIPTION,
                                 USAGE_TYPE,
                                 PRODUCT,
                                 JURISDICTION,
                                 PROVIDER,
                                 RATE_PERIOD,
                                 FLAGFALL,
                                 RATE,
                                 RATEBAND,
                                 NUMSECS,
                                 BAND_RATE,
                                 ACTIVE_DT,
                                 INACTIVE_DT)
                                 select /*+ use_hash(rate_usage_overrides,corridor_plan_id_values,product_elements,descriptions,jurisdictions,rate_usage_bands_overrides) */
                                 distinct
                                 decode(a.corridor_plan_id,0, '''', (select c.short_display from corridor_plan_id_values c where a.corridor_plan_id = c.corridor_plan_id)) AS SSR_CODE,
                                 a.corridor_plan_id AS CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID,
                                 decode(a.corridor_plan_id,0, '''', (select d.display_value from corridor_plan_id_values d where a.corridor_plan_id = d.corridor_plan_id)) AS CORRIDOR_PLAN_DESCRIPTION,


                                 decode(a.type_id_usg,0, '''', (select f.description_text from usage_types e, descriptions f where a.type_id_usg = e.type_id_usg and e.description_code = f.description_code)) AS USAGE_TYPE,

                                 decode(a.element_id,0, '''', (select h.description_text from product_elements g,descriptions h where a.element_id = g.element_id and g.description_code = h.description_code)) AS PRODUCT,

                                 decode(a.jurisdiction,0, '''', (select j.description_text from jurisdictions i,descriptions j where a.jurisdiction = i.jurisdiction and j.description_code = i.description_code)) AS JURISDICTION,

                                 decode(a.provider_class,0, '''', (select k.display_value from provider_class_values k where a.provider_class = k.provider_class)) AS PROVIDER,
                                 decode(a.rate_period,''0'', '''',(select l.display_value from rate_period_values       l where a.rate_period = l.rate_period)) AS RATE_PERIOD,
                                 (a.FIXED_CHARGE_AMT/100) + (a.ADD_FIXED_AMT/10000000) AS FLAGFALL,
                                 (a.ADD_UNIT_RATE/10000000) * 60 AS RATE,
                                 b.RATEBAND AS RATEBAND,
                                 b.NUM_UNITS AS NUMSECS,
                                 (b.UNIT_RATE/10000000) * 60 AS BAND_RATE,
                                 a.ACTIVE_DT AS ACTIVE_DT,
                                 a.INACTIVE_DT AS INACTIVE_DT
                                 from rate_usage_overrides a,
                                 rate_usage_bands_overrides b
                                 where a.seqnum = b.seqnum(+)';



            var_cursor := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

                DBMS_SQL.PARSE(var_cursor,prv_rp_insert_sql,DBMS_SQL.V7);

                v_Dummy:= DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(var_cursor);

                DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(var_cursor);

                         COMMIT;

                         /* Create the indexes */
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_RATE_PLAN_ID';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_USAGE_TYPE';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_SSR_CODE';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS_PROV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PD_JR_PV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_JURIS';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_PROV';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX RRP_UT_PROV';


                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(CORRIDOR_PLAN_ID, USAGE_TYPE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX RRP_RATE_PLAN_ID ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(RATE_PLAN_ID) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_SSR_CODE ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(SSR_CODE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_USAGE_TYPE ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT) TABLESPACE PRV_Index  STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, JURISDICTION) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_JURIS_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, JURISDICTION, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PD_JR_PV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, JURISDICTION, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_JURIS ON  PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, JURISDICTION) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROD_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PRODUCT, PROVIDER) TABLESPACE PRV_Index STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX RRP_UT_PROV ON PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC(USAGE_TYPE, PROVIDER)  TABLESPACE PRV_Index  STORAGE( PCTINCREASE 0 )';

                         /* Cut over to the new tables */
                         LOCK TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN IN EXCLUSIVE  MODE ;

                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_X';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN';
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_X RENAME TO PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC';

                         /* Remove the old data */
                         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE PRICEVIEW_RATE_PLAN_PROC';
```

end;
/

Comment: I didnot get you..the same query i have inserted so wat us the difference in my query and yours?

Comment: @gangas I removed procedure and I include begin

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just execute the procedure from SQL*Plus  ?

```
BEGIN
  execute  PRICEVIEW_PROCESS_EXTRACT.SP_PROCESS_RATE_PLAN;
END;
```

This makes the assumption that

1. The package PRICEVIEW_PROCESS_EXTRACT has a definition of the SP_PROCESS_RATE_PLAN in the PACKAGE SPEC so it can be called from outside the package.
2. You are either the owner of the package or you have been granted execute on the procedure

If not, then can you add it to the package specification and have the grant made ?

Comment: CAn ANYONE answer this query?

Comment: it tells PRICEVIEW_PROCESS_EXTRACT package is invalid.